# How to define how much seconds Client socket try to connect to the server?

Tags: python, sockets, connection, client

How to define how much seconds Client socket try to connect to the server ?

Example:

```
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'

TCP_PORT = 5005

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

Note:

Now, the client socket try to connect to the server until the client socket is close or the connection succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the socket [non-blocking](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking), and then wait with a timeout with [`select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) for the socket to become writable. When `select` says the socket it writable, you are connected.

As for the actual internal timeouts in the IP-stack, at least on Windows they didn't use to be configurable. If there was problem connecting then it would take about 45 seconds for all retries to time out.

Comment: Can I use `time.time()` before and after the `connect()` to satisfy the need?

Comment: @zhangyangyu The `time.time` function only returns the current time, it will not stop `connect` from blocking or be used as a timer.

Comment: Yes. I think the OP means to get the running time of `connect`. In his blocking case, adding 2 `time.time` and their difference seems to be the running time.

Comment: I try to learn from the tutorial, but it no have a wide explanation, you have other tutorial or examples that define 2 - 3 seconds (non-blocking socket) for trying to connect in the client ?